# NSDateFormatter can't format previous stored date

Tags: ios, nsdate, nsdateformatter

I am passing a `Date` stored in `Dictionary` to this block of code to get a string value of trimmed Date as '`dd-MM`', Problem is am getting the trimmed version of the current Date as a return and not the Date i have passed. please help to trim the Date i have passed.

```
-(NSString *)trimDate : (NSDate *) date
{
    NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [formatter setDateFormat:@"dd-MM"];

    NSString *result = [formatter stringFromDate:[NSDate date]];

    return  result;
}
```

Comment: only need to pass date instead of [NSDate date];Because [NSDate date]returning current date and time of ur timezone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to change this

```
NSString *result = [formatter stringFromDate:[NSDate date]];
```

to

```
NSString *result = [formatter stringFromDate:date];
```

Check this

```
-(NSString *)trimDate : (NSDate *) date
{
    NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [formatter setDateFormat:@"dd-MM"];

    NSString *result = [formatter stringFromDate:date];

    return  result;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

please replace the following line:

```
NSString *result = [formatter stringFromDate:[NSDate date]];
```

by this line :

```
NSString *result = [formatter stringFromDate:date];
```

hope this will help you.